# Data table count rows in lightning web component from server side

Tags: soql, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I'm having a hard time on how to use count in lightning web components.
I just want to count how many Active users and how many Inactive users. Can someone please help I'm having a trouble in implementing this in Controller and in JS so that I can display this in my HTML. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [ask], and take the [tour]. As your question is written, we can't really answer it at this time. Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried so far? Do you get any errors? Please [edit] your question to demonstrate the code you've used so far, research you've tried, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Can You update below code in your controller.It will return as expected result of Active Users. If we use IsActive=false it will return inactive users and you will get count.
select Id, name, isActive,count(isActive)  from User where IsActive=true groupby name;